# JSoup - Add onclick function to the anchor href

Tags: java, xml-parsing, jsoup

Existing HTMl Document

```
<a href="http://google.com">Link</a>
```

Like to convert it as:

```
<a href="#" onclick="openFunction('http://google.com')">Link</a>
```

Using JSoup Java library many fancy parsing can be done. But not able to find clue to add attribute like above requirement. Please help.

Comment: Please elaborate your question, also parsing Google is a bad idea.

Comment: You have down voted before by edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To set an attribute have a look at [the doc](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/modifying-data/set-attributes)

```
String html = "<html><head><title>First parse</title></head>"
              + "<body><p>Parsed HTML into a doc.</p><a href=\"http://google.com\">Link</a></body></html>";
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);   

Elements links = doc.getElementsByTag("a");
for (Element element : links) {
    element.attr("onclick", "openFunction('"+element.attr("href")+"')");
    element.attr("href", "#");
}

System.out.println(doc.html());
```

Will change :

```
<a href="http://google.com">
```

into

```
<a href="#" onclick="openFunction('http://google.com')">Link</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `Element#attr`. I just used a loop but you can do it however you want.

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse("<a href=\"http://google.com\">Link</a>");
for (Element e : doc.getElementsByTag("a")){
    if (e.text().equals("Link")){
        e.attr("onclick", "openFunction('http://google.com')");
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

### Output

```
<a href="http://google.com" onclick="openFunction('http://google.com')">Link</a>
```